# What is the purpose of SecureBlackbox.dll present under the "C:\Windows\Lenovo" folder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo laptop with Windows 10 installed and while browsing through files under `C:\Windows\Lenovo` I came across a set of files that look suspicious to me.

These files are present under the directory `C:\Windows\Lenovo\ImController\Service` :

```
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM          55968 ClientBrokerAgent.Net.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         117040 Lenovo.CertificateValidation.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM          44368 Lenovo.ImController.EventLogging.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         207192 Lenovo.Modern.CoreTypes.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM          79792 Lenovo.Modern.ImController.ContractBroker.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         110000 Lenovo.Modern.ImController.EventManager.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM          81840 Lenovo.Modern.ImController.exe
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM          98136 Lenovo.Modern.ImController.ImClient.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM          63920 Lenovo.Modern.ImController.PluginManager.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         190896 Lenovo.Modern.ImController.Shared.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM          74160 Lenovo.Modern.ImController.UpdateManager.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         133464 Lenovo.Modern.Utilities.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         246144 Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         708936 Newtonsoft.Json.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM        3828608 SecureBlackbox.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         107904 SecureBlackbox.HTTP.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         110464 SecureBlackbox.HTTPCommon.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM          63360 SecureBlackbox.LDAP.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         409984 SecureBlackbox.PGP.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         212352 SecureBlackbox.SSLClient.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         130944 SecureBlackbox.SSLCommon.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         255360 SecureBlackbox.XML.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM         518528 SecureBlackbox.XMLSecurity.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM          36800 System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
-a----        11-01-2021  09:13 PM        3902336 Windows.winmd
```

I'm unable to find any information about the `SecureBlackbox` files.
Any idea what these are for? Is it bloatware by Lenovo?

Comment: Yes; ImController absolutely is bloatware and unnecessary.  I highly encourage Lenovo owners to uninstall it.  Lenovo is known to self-sign their files, have that certificate be compromised, allowing malware authors to sign their code.  Their software is a nuisance to the entire world.

Answer (score 1):

[SecureBlackBox](https://www.qbssoftware.com/secureblackbox.html)
is a well-known software library/DLL, defined as:

> Suite of software components that allows developers to add strong security to their applications to protect binary data, files, documents and e-mails.
>
> SecureBlackbox is a suite of software components that allows developers to add strong security to their applications to protect binary data, files, documents and e-mails. SecureBlackbox includes authentic implementations (no 3rd-party code used) of various data security standards and network communication protocols for various platforms (Windows, .NET, Linux, MacOS X / iOS, Java / Android).

The version you see is very likely the .NET edition of the software.
It is also highly likely that removing it will cause the containing `ImController`
Lenovo software to malfunction.

[`ImController`](https://www.file.net/process/lenovo.modern.imcontroller.exe.html)
is a component Lenovo installs on their Windows systems to provide
additional features such as the Lenovo Vantage system.
I wouldn't suggest deleting it, unless you have decided to get rid of all
Lenovo applications pre-installed on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of Lenovo laptops here and the only folder in C:\Windows\Lenovo is IM Controller.

I do not have SecureBlackBox on my machine. It is associated with Lenovo Service Bridge and I am currently not using Service Bridge (identifies your particular computer).

[Lenovo Service Bridge](https://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Lenovo-Service-Bridge-159044-program.aspx)

> Files installed by Lenovo Service Bridge Program executable:  lsb.exe
> Name: Lenovo Service Bridge
> Path: C:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\lenovo\lenovo service
> bridge\lsb.exe Additional files: Uninstaller.exe - Lenovo Service
> Bridge Uninstaller unins000.exe - Setup/Uninstall
> ClickOnceUninstaller.exe - ClickOnceUninstaller CreateWTSTask.exe
> Adup.dll - Adup Common.dll - Common DownloadManager.dll -
> DownloadManager Lenovo.CertificateValidation.dll -
> Lenovo.CertificateValidation LSBUpdater.exe - LSBUpdater LscShim.exe -
> LscShim OsDiag.dll - OsDiag SecureBlackbox.HTTPCommon.dll (by /n
> software inc) - SecureBlackbox (SecureBlackbox.NET library)
> SecureBlackbox.SSLCommon.dll (by /n software inc) SysDetect.dll -
> SysDetect Newtonsoft.Json.dll (by Newtonsoft) - Json.NET (Json.NET
> .NET 3.5) SecureBlackbox.dll SecureBlackbox.HTTP.dll
> SecureBlackbox.LDAP.dll SecureBlackbox.PGP.dll
> SecureBlackbox.SSLClient.dll SecureBlackbox.XML.dll
> SecureBlackbox.XMLSecurity.dll SysDiag.dll - SysDiag LSB.vshost.exe
> (by Microsoft) - Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2015 (vshost.exe)

There is no real need to uninstall Service Bridge if you have it installed.

But do not uninstall or delete IM Controller.

It is used in a number of items in the Lenovo System Interface Foundation V2 Driver in Device Manager.

IM Controller is also part of Lenovo Vantage and Vantage includes the Battery Threshold Manager. You can enable Lenovo Battery Management to keep an always-plugged in Laptop at 80% charge. Read up on that because it is very useful.

So do not try to uninstall IM Controller (and so also System Interface Foundation.).